# Cannot authorise with reddit via oauth2

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, reddit

I am trying to implement oauth2 with reddit and im running into problems at every step of the way, i was using an oauth library for codeigniter but that wouldnt work, so i decided to scrap it and try to do it myself.

this is the authorize request, if im not logged in on reddit i get the login page, if i am or after logging in i get an error.

https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=myclientid&scope=identity&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fregister

and it redirects me back to here:

mydomain.com/register?state=None&error=invalid_request

i cant find any useful documentation on the Reddit oauth implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little bit about [reddit's OAuth2](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#wiki-authorization-parameters) on the github wiki for reddit's source. It appears you're missing the `state` parameter in the initial request.

> state - You can pass a value into the authorization page that will be included in the redirect back to you if the user grants access. This is useful for preventing cross-site request forgery (CSRF). By choosing (and remembering) a sufficiently random value, you can ensure that the request that comes back to your site was initiated by visiting the authorization URL you generated.

(The quoted wiki info is incorrect in that `state` is actually required; I'll update the wiki shortly)

Comment: Thank you kemitche! Seems to have worked perfectly, i've read elsewhere on stackoverflow Reddit's oAuth implementation is a little unique, are there any other quirks im likely to come across?

After successfull authorization with Reddit, im trying to call  https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me, with the authorization_code set, after trying this via POST and GET im getting this error:

403 Forbidden
Request forbidden by administrative rules

Comment: Problem sorted, i wasnt sending the Authorization: header properly. For anyone else running into issues i would strongly recommend reading this: http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/197x36/using_oauth_to_send_valid_requests/c8lz57u